# Exclude specific jar from p2 repo in my eclipse plugin build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I have this p2 repo added in pom.xml

```
<repository>
        <id>editor</id>
        <url>${editors.url}</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

and it has com.*.editors.text_***.jar

I am want to exclude this jar or feature while building my pom.xml

Comment: Instead of the `<repository>`, you need a target definition file which has to be build in the parent POM as first module (e.g. [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/pom.xml#L32) and [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/target-platform/idealized-target.target)). For details see [Tycho tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html).

Comment: not completely understand but I would like to go through the given example. Thanks